# Glitchy CSS Animations Wit Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

The following code works exactly as expected besides a couple of quirks

The first is that when hovering over the capital "T" or "H" headers the animation is very glitchy and sometimes isn't even performed correctly. The two divs at the bottom are to prove that the animations are smooth and work perfectly. There is also no difference in performance when `hover` is used instead of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

**Why is the animation spazzing out like that?**

The second issue is the animation skipping to the beginning of `fade-out-left` when you quickly swipe your mouse over either the headers or the trigger divs at the bottom.
I've tried using `.is(':animated')` to only run `fade-out-left` when the first is finished, but the value is never true. I've also tried `.bind('animationend')` but when I fix the skipping issue, it doesn't play the `fade-out-left` animation when quickly swiping over.

I feel like this is a common animation problem, but I haven't been able to find any information on it. **How do I prevent the animation from skipping when quickly swiping over it?**

```js
// Content
$('.char').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).next().addClass('animate');
});
$('.char').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).next().removeClass('animate');
});

// Triggers
$('.trigger').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#' + $(this)[0].id[0] + '-container').find('.line').addClass('animate');
});
$('.trigger').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#' + $(this)[0].id[0] + '-container').find('.line').removeClass('animate');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}


/* Content */

.segment {
  display: inline;
}

.char {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-name: fade-out-left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-play-state: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: reverse;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: fade-in-right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-play-state: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}


/* Animations */

@keyframes fade-in-right {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out-left {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-20px);
  }
}

/* Triggers */

#triggers-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.trigger {
  position: inline;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#t-trigger {
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

#h-trigger {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Content -->
  <div id="t-container" class="container">
    <div class="char segment">T</div>
    <div class="line segment">his is some text.</div>
  </div>
  <div id="h-container" class="container">
    <div class="char segment">H</div>
    <div class="line segment">ere is some more text.</div>
  </div>

  <!-- Triggers -->
  <div id="triggers-container">
    <div id="t-trigger" class="trigger">T</div>
    <div id="h-trigger" class="trigger">H</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After thinking about it, you really don't need JS for simple mouse enter events.
I redo all you example with pure CSS, allow you to add new line without JS update, etc..

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.container {
  pointer-events: none;
}
.container > div { 
  display: inline-block;
}
.container .char { 
  pointer-events: auto;
  background: yellow;
}
.container:nth-child(2) .char {
  background: green;
}
.container .line { 
  transform: translateX(-1em);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.container:hover .line {
  transform: translateX(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="container">
      <div class="char segment">T</div>
      <div class="line segment">his is some text.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="char segment">L</div>
      <div class="line segment">orem ipsum</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="char segment">T</div>
      <div class="line segment">his is new text</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was just about to ask that. This solved the problem *and* refactored javascript completely out of the code. I tried doing that myself but it just didn't click for me. @Arthur you should copy-paste this into your other answer so I can accept it bc you answered all of my problems :)

Answer (score 2):

add **z-index** to **char** class to avoid the glitch, like this

```js
// Content
$('.char').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).next().addClass('animate');
});
$('.char').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).next().removeClass('animate');
});

// Triggers
$('.trigger').mouseenter(function() {
  $('#' + $(this)[0].id[0] + '-container').find('.line').addClass('animate');
});
$('.trigger').mouseleave(function() {
  $('#'+ $(this)[0].id[0] + '-container').find('.line').removeClass('animate');
});
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

/* Content */

.segment {
  display: inline;
}

.char {
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
  z-index:999;
}

.line {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  
  animation-name: fade-out-left;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-play-state: ease-in;
  animation-fill-mode: reverse;
}

.animate {
  animation-name: fade-in-right;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-play-state: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* Animations */

@keyframes fade-in-right {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-20px);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
}

@keyframes fade-out-left {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translatex(0);
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translatex(-20px);
  }
}



/* Triggers */

#triggers-container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.trigger {
  position: inline;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#t-trigger {
  float: left;
  background-color: gray;
}

#h-trigger {
  float: right;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Content -->
    <div id="t-container" class="container">
      <div class="char segment">T</div>
      <div class="line segment">his is some text.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="h-container" class="container">
      <div class="char segment">H</div>
      <div class="line segment">ere is some more text.</div>
    </div>

    <!-- Triggers -->
    <div id="triggers-container">
      <div id="t-trigger" class="trigger">T</div>
      <div id="h-trigger" class="trigger">H</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is the good solution. The problem is when you over the first letter, the text next to it is displayed just between the first letter and the mouse, so you leave the first letter, and the text is hide, so you re-enter on it, etc...

If you want the text on top of first letter, you can forget the z-index update and add `.line { pointer-events:none }` (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Comment: ok, so you want the text to keep displayed when you leave the first letter and enter the text ?

Comment: I'm not the host, just add some explanation to your answer

Comment: ah sorry, didn't pay attention :)

Comment: @Arthur yes it seems a bit weird but it's behaving as intended. The only problem was the glitchiness which seems to be fixed by adding a `z-index`

Comment: Just try to help you to understand your problem, and give you another solution. The Temani's solution work well

Comment: @Arthur tbh the last sentence went a bit over my head but I appreciate the effort :)